# Angular 2 Dependency Injection not working

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

Hello I have been trying to figure this out for about 2 days now i cannot see where in going wrong. I am getting a some errors that i am not sure how to debug.

no provider for AppService

I have recreated this in a plunker

I think that the problem is that I don't register AppService anyware.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[Click Here For plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FK1NSxrPwZUlqnW9Ju9s?p=preview)

Comment: See also the comments below my answer that revealed another issue in your Plunker.

Comment: thank you, this was part of the issue. I am still getting an error but a different one. i will research it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Injectable()
export class AppService{
```

should be

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService{
```

```
provoder:[AppService]
```

should be

```
providers:[AppService]
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Lcdwz2t1Ri3xf115hn4N?p=preview)

If you want a single instance of your service for your whole application add it to providers of `AppModule` as other answers suggest. If you want an instance per `AppComponent` (which is usually also a single one for your whole application) then keep it where it is. Other services provided at module level won't be able to inject `AppService` this way though.

Comment: the Injectable() decorator works even without `@`, how comes that Please ?

Comment: Actually it doesn't but checking in Plunker revealed another bug in your code. The constructor is missing a body `{}` and is therefore ignored. You only need `@Injectable()` if the class' constructor has parameters. In this case, because the constructor is ignored, the class is treated as if it doesn't have a constructor (or as one that only has a default constructor) which doesn't need the decorator.

Comment: Thank you indeed , PS: I'm not the question owner but i've asked you since you are an angular2 gold badged. Thanks;)

Comment: Ah, right. Thanks for the question anyway as it revealed another mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add AppService to the `providers` array:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ],
  providers: [AppService]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You can read more about Angular2 Dependency Injection here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html

Comment: this solved the plunker but not the issue I'm having, one that I am having on my machine. I will read more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Add

`providers: [AppService],`

in your `@NgModule` as follow :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  providers: [ AppService ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You were right, you needed to declare your service to your module to be able to use it as a DI.